# Get unix 'top' command output from Expect script

Tags: unix, top, expect

All,
**EDIT**
I want to execute a unix statement in Expect script and get an output without having to include the interact statement.The unix statement outputs  rsize value for a process.  I haven't programmed in Expect before.
This is my code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect
 set some_host "some host"
 set Mycmd "top -l 1 -stats pid,rsize,command | grep Process_Name| awk '{print \$2};'"
 spawn telnet localhost $some_host
 expect "login:"
 send "myDevice\r"
 expect "Password:"
 send "$password\r"
 expect "\$"
 send "$Mycmd\r"   
 interact
```

If I don't include the interact statement, I don't get any output. How do I get this to work so that I get the correct rsize value as the output?

Comment: Telnet. **shudders**.

Comment: For one thing I certainly would not use telnet....maybe a keyed login version of ssh to send the command.

Comment: Feels like 1992 in here all of a sudden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the output of `ps`?

```
$ ps -p <pid> -o rss | egrep '[0-9]'
```

Remotely, you can do this over ssh:

```
$ ssh user@host ps -p <pid> -o rss | egrep '[0-9]'
```

Comment: Thanks @ErikA: I ended up using ssh. Had to set up ssh keys for password-less SSH login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of these methods, each has slightly different results.

```
expect -re "*\n"
expect
expect "%"
```

You should also look at the meaning of `match_max` which controls how much will be matched.

after the results are caught, you will want to look the results

```
puts "$expect_out(buffer)"
```

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect for some great examples.

Comment: Will definitely try this..